# My connexion_id() changes during the execution of my SQL script, making it fail

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

So I have a sql script which does basic select requests :

```
    SELECT ref_cle, ref_name INTO @ref_cle, @ref_name FROM MyBase.MyTable
```

Further in the script, I call a stored procedure. It uses the CONNECTION_ID() and that's how I know it changes...

```
    call MyBase.MyFunction(@refle_cle,@ref_name,CONNECTION_ID());
```

After that line, the @ref_cle and ref_name variables are valued to null, and connexion_id() has incremented. The variables are not modified in the procedure (even if I doubt it changes anything to the problem) but the connexion_id() returns the value+1 of the connexion_id() used in the procedure.

So the problem is that because the connexion_id() changes, my variables are set to null and the end of my script fails. How can I change that, either by configuring MySQL or by changing my script.

Thank you.

Comment: Is `connexion_id()` a user-defined function, or do you mean `CONNECTION_ID()`? I've tried it, and `CONNECTION_ID()` does not seem to change during or after execution of a stored procedure. So maybe the issue is in the way you're calling the code.

Comment: @ChrisLear Yes, i'm refering to CONNECTION_ID(), pardon my french. I'm not able to see a change when I use it on my PC, but some customers with multiple connections to the said MySQL instance have the problem.